# Can network admin track obfuscated vpn?

Tags: vpn

I have been using an alcatel hotspot that has been provided to me and I was seeing if they can see my history/app activity even with a obfuscated vpn connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "obfuscated VPN"? Do you simply mean "encrypted VPN"?

Answer (score 0):

They should not be able to see what websites/apps you use, but they can figure out that you are using a VPN (and possibly, which VPN you're using).

Comment: Unless ther eis a DNS leak, and then they can

Comment: Yes but isn't the assumption that is a working and secure VPN?

Comment: Not if the *host* is configured to send DNS queries outside the VPN. We have a ton of posts here on this topic. Lookup "DNS leak"

Comment: The host chooses the route for traffic. The VPN is just one network.

Comment: You do not understand how operating systems use and set up networks and VPNs. Please  refresh your knowledge of routing and network paths.

Answer (score 0):

Usually just getting the destination IP from your outgoing VPN traffic, and then doing a reverse DNS lookup, will not work. However, if they want to spent the time, they can compile/get a list of IPs for the hosts used by the usual VPN providers. The later is popular with nations which are a bit more subtle about blocking VPN access.

Comment: Or if DNS queries are sent outside the VPN tunnel, which can happen/